# Malloc of pointer to an array- C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, malloc

I have a function which gets as a parameter a pointer to array, 
e.g. `int** segs`.
I need to allocate (in the function-body) memory for the array, which has size 100 for example.
My attempt was:

```
*segs=(int*)(malloc(100));
```

So far so good.
I put a value into `*segs[0]`, and still everything is great.
But... when I try to reach `*segs[1]`, I get an "invalid write of size 4" error from valgrind, which leads to seg-fault.
I have no idea why does that happen.
I tried to reach to `*segs[2]`, but then I get even something weirder-

> Error of uninitialised value of size 8.

Comment: Please try to create an [mcve] to show us of your attempt.

Comment: Did you really mean C++? Because this sounds like C code. There is zero reason to write code like this in C++.

Comment: *I put a value into* `*segs[0]` - be care of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Either disambiguate, e.g `(*segs)[0] = ...` or use a local var and save to your target ptr-to-ptr after everything else is done.

Comment: Is there anything at `*segs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `*segs[N]` is treated as `*(segs[N])`, which is ok when `N` is equal to `0`. However, when you do the same thing using the index 1, things break since nothing has been allocated for `segs[1]`

For any index other than zero, you need to use `(*segs)[N]`.

It will be easier to use a temporary pointer in the function.

```
int* ptr = (int*)(malloc(100));
*segs = ptr;

// and then

ptr[0] = ...;  // Good
ptr[1] = ...;  // Good

...


ptr[99] = ...; // Still good
```

#### Upgrading to C++ Way

1. Pass the pointer by reference.

   ```
   void foo(int*& segs) { ... }
   ```
2. Use `new` instead of `malloc` to allocate memory.

   ```
   segs = new int[100];
   ```
3. Better yet, use `std::vector` insteady raw arrays.

   ```
   void foo(std::vector<int>& segs) { ... }
   ```